# JavaScript: change function(this) to function(this.id)

Tags: javascript

I have This `javascript` function for open [kcfinder](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/) file manager url for textbox.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function openKCFinder(field) {
    window.KCFinder = {
        callBack: function(url) {
            field.value = url;
            window.KCFinder = null;
        }
    };
    window.open("http://localhost/cms/kc/browse.php?type=video&dir=files/public", "kcfinder_textbox",
        "status=0, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, " +
        "resizable=1, scrollbars=0, width=800, height=600"
    );
}

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input id="video" onclick="openKCFinder(this)" class="form-control" type="text" name="video" placeholder="add video"> // i need to change openKCFinder(this.id)

<input id="audio" onclick="openKCFinder(this)" class="form-control" type="text" name="video" placeholder="add video"> // i need to change openKCFinder(this.id)
```

now i need to change `(this)` to `(this.id)` for change `type` of open `url`. ie: if `textbox/input id="video"` Then `type=video` Or if `textbox/input id="audio"`, `type=audio`.

How to change this function for my need?

DEMO [Kcfinder Textbox](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/demos/textbox)

Comment: currently with `openKCFinder(this)` `field` becomes this, so you can wrap the window open into `if (field.id === 'video') { }`

Comment: @metadings: You right! this worked Now. for each id `if(){}`? or `if else` better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function openKCFinder(field) {
    window.KCFinder = {
        callBack: function(url) {
            field.value = url;
            window.KCFinder = null;
        }
    };
    if (field.id === 'video') {
        window.open("http://localhost/cms/kc/browse.php?type=video&dir=files/public", "kcfinder_textbox",
            "status=0, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, " +
            "resizable=1, scrollbars=0, width=800, height=600"
        );
    }
    else if (field.id === 'audio') {
        // open something else
    }
    else {
        // handle something unknown
    }
}

</script>
```

Or if you're sure about the ids, you could also do

```
window.open("http://localhost/cms/kc/browse.php?type=" + field.id + "&dir=files/public", "kcfinder_textbox",
    "status=0, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, " +
    "resizable=1, scrollbars=0, width=800, height=600"
);
```

You may also be interested in [MDN's documentation of the HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), which describes the properties you have with `this` in `field`.